# problem in use aggregate functions in laravel-7 - selectRaw()

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-7

i want get 15 number of my products from my mysql dataBase that has most sell

this is my query:

```
SELECT *, products.name, ( SELECT COUNT(orders.product_id) 
                            FROM orders 
                            WHERE products.id = orders.product_id 
                            ) AS saleCount
FROM products
GROUP BY products.name
ORDER BY saleCount DESC
LIMIT 15
```

i use query in laravel like this:

```
Product::select('*')
        ->selectRaw(
            '(select COUNT(orders.product_id) 
                    FROM orders 
                    WHERE products.id = orders.product_id) as saleCount'
        )
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->orderBy('saleCount', 'DESC')
        ->limit(15)
        ->get();
```

But I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bigg.products.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select *, (select COUNT(orders.product_id) FROM orders WHERE products.id = orders.product_id) as saleCount from `products` where `products`.`deleted_at` is null group by `products`.`id` order by `saleCount` desc limit 15)

I don't know where I went wrong. Thank you for your help

Comment: Add the column to the group by like `->groupBy(['products.id', 'bigg.products.name'])`.

Comment: i tried this but i got another error like this and asked this time for Product_label and ... @DigitalDrifter

Comment: Yep, you need to add ALL the columns you're aggregating to the array passed to group by.

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bigg.products.label' isn't in GROUP BY @DigitalDrifter

Comment: Add `bigg.products.label` like I did `bigg.products.name` in my earlier comment.

Comment: thank you for your help my problem was solved @DigitalDrifter